# Why does my Windows 7 PC refuse to use any DNS server?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns

My laptop has suddenly failed to connect to the internet. The Wireless Network connection is still there, but it says it does not have an Internet connection.
When I try to diagnose the problem in Windows it says that it fails to do DNS lookups.
My iPhone is able to connect and use the same WLAN without any problems.

Things I have already tried to resolve this:

Changed the DNS servers in the IPv4 properties. To several different public DNS servers, including Google's without any success.

I have also tried to use my iPhone as a shared network conneciton point for my PC, but it still has the same problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or have some ideas for other diagnostics I shold try to discover more about the porblem?

Answer (score 3):

When you change the DNS settings, try running `ipconfig /flushdns` to let your PC start with fresh DNS cache.

Secondly, try releasing and renewing the ip address (also refreshes the network settings) by
`ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`

Answer (score 0):

Is there multiple network connection? Try to leave on the network connection for internet and disable all other connection.